# Is there any way to make this code shorter and simpler i.e by using some sort of for loop?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have done it so that if the user enters "g" as an input it will convert it to "green"..."r"=red.."c"= cyan ....so forth

is there any way to use a loop of some sort to do this instead? thanks

```
for i in range(3):
    findColours = input("Enter you're colours -Choose from [red, green, blue, orange, magenta, cyan]:")
    if findColours == "r":
        findColours = "red"
    elif findColours =="g":
        findColours = "green"
    elif findColours =="b":
            findColours = "blue"
    elif findColours =="o":
            findColours = "orange"
    elif findColours =="m":
            findColours = "magenta"
    elif findColours =="c":
            findColours = "cyan"
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but that should be "your colors" not "you're colors".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a dictionary for this. Here is the idea:

```py
colors = {"r": "red", "g": "green", "b": "blue", "o": "orange", "m": "magenta", "c", "cyan"}

for i in range(3):
   inputColour = input("Enter you're colours -Choose from [red, green, blue, orange, magenta, cyan]:")

   try:
      findColours = colors[inputColor]
   except:
      # handle exceptions here
```

Hope this helps!